# How to correctly work with ExtensionObject and Struct in milo opc ua

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I would like to ask how should I work correctly with Struct when I am trying to read some object from opc ua server. I went trough this [example](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/e854374845e6c5f46a7b033c2c62cee2ee10622a/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/UnifiedAutomationReadCustomDataTypeExample.java#L43-L48) and I was able to read the data.

But right now I don't know how to **correctly** read them. Let's imagine I am reading some datastructure including two arrays for x and y values. I tried to do something like this:

```java
 Float[] x = (Float[])struct.getMember("x").getValue()
 Float[] y = (Float[])struct.getMember("y").getValue()
```

but I receive exception "Cannot cast 'java.lang.Object[]' to 'java.lang.Float[]'" I am able to do it this way:

```java
float[] x = new float[100];
        int i = 0;
        for(Object o: (Object[])struct.getMember("x").getValue()){
            x[i] = (Float)o;
            i++;
        }
```

but I don't think this could be right.

Anyway I would like to achieve something similar like reading json file with jackson. To have some class with same naming asi the "members are and with suitable types and do something like:

```java
OpcuaReader reader = ...
MyClass myClass = reader.read(struct, MyClass.class)
```

I could be totally wrong so could anyone suggest me how should I solve such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot cast array of objects like that.
Instead, you could use the stream API to construct Floats like this:

```
Object[] objectArray = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3, 4, 5 };
Float floatArray[] = Arrays.stream(objectArray)
  .map(Object::toString)
  .map(Float::valueOf)
  .toArray(Float[]::new);
```

About the Milo client, there is a great example of reading custom data types in [ReadWriteCustomDataTypeNodeExample](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/e854374845e6c5f46a7b033c2c62cee2ee10622a/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/ReadWriteCustomDataTypeNodeExample.java).

You can create your own type similar to `CustomStructType` and override the decode method for yourself. The decoder also has a built in `readFloatArray` method in hand:

```
@Override
public CustomStructType decode(
    SerializationContext context,
    UaDecoder decoder) throws UaSerializationException {

    String foo = decoder.readString("Foo");
    UInteger bar = decoder.readUInt32("Bar");
    boolean baz = decoder.readBoolean("Baz");

    Float[] floatArray = decoder.readFloatArray("floatArray");

    return new CustomStructType(foo, bar, baz);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will try to go trough it. This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I went trough the code and I am not quite sure what for are "getTypeId" and "getBinaryEncodingId" methods and how should I handle them.

Comment: I am getting this exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.Struct cannot be cast to class OpcuaCurve (org.eclipse.milo.opcua.binaryschema.Struct and OpcuaCurve are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: What kind of OPC server are you connected to? Did you define "OpcuaCurve" on the server first? In the example, the decoder returns `CustomStructType` already, so there should not be a cast exception, if you register the codec and write your decode as it can be seen in the example. 
This is how CustomStructType looks on the example server: https://i.imgur.com/8qgdXmE.png

Comment: I haven't implemented the server on my own, I need to read the data from plc server. This is what I see when I use UaExpert https://imgur.com/a/wUZNT1s.

Comment: I am not sure how I should over ride these two in example: https://imgur.com/a/GK4wmoc Rest seams to be clear for me.

Comment: Maybe this screenshot from UaExpert explains it better: https://prnt.sc/vqgkzm

Comment: TYPE_ID supposed to reference the DataType node, in your case, try something like `public static final ExpandedNodeId TYPE_ID = ExpandedNodeId.parse("ns=3;s=DT_PrServo_typeRuntime ... ");` You sould be able to browse the referenced DataType in the UaExpert browser too. That data type refernces `HasEncoding`, its node id supposed to be the BINARY_ENCODING_ID.
https://i.imgur.com/KsZFD4B.png

Comment: This is what I have found in UaExpert under Types/DataTypes/OPC Binary: https://prnt.sc/vqm7c8 and this is what I find under Types/DataTypes/BaseData Type: https://prnt.sc/vqm8cu so I guess I use the second one (the NamespaceIndex and Identifier) for TYPE_ID but I am not sure where I should get the BINARY_ENCODING_ID. Is it the first one I have found?

Comment: On the second screen, bottom-right corner: `HasEncoding: Default Binary` Double click on that and use its node id as the BINARY_ENCODING_ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225168/discussion-between-jakub-znamenacek-and-istibekesi).

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to ***istibekesi***, we manage to get it working. For someone who would have same problem here is what you need to do:

**1) Find the TYPE_ID**

- you need to find the NamespaceIndex and Identifier of the DataType of the structure (object) you want to read over OPC UA using for example [UaExpert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html)
- if you are not sure which DataType it is just find some variable representing this structure and there you will see the DataType info on the right side of the screen when you click on it.

**2) Find the BINARY_ENCODING_ID**

- to find this one you need to search for the DataType itself using UaExpert it will be some were under Types/DataTypes ...
- when you find it click on it for more info
- then on the right bottom part of your screen there will be "HasEncoding|Default Binary" and you double click on it
- this way you will receive the NamespaceIndex and the Identifier for BINARY_ENCODING_ID

**3) Follow this [example](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/e854374845e6c5f46a7b033c2c62cee2ee10622a/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client/ReadWriteCustomDataTypeNodeExample.java)**

- To have all parts of milo you need you will need to include **sdk-client**, **dictionary-reader**, **bsd-parser** in your dependencies
- create class similar to this:

```java
public class OpcuaCurve implements UaStructure {

    public static final ExpandedNodeId TYPE_ID = ExpandedNodeId.parse("ns=3;s=DT_\"PrServo_typeRuntimeDriveDiagnosticsProcessValuesTrends\".\"hmiTrend\"");

    public static final ExpandedNodeId BINARY_ENCODING_ID = ExpandedNodeId.parse("ns=3;s=TE_\"PrServo_typeRuntimeDriveDiagnosticsProcessValuesTrends\".\"hmiTrend\"");

    private final Float[] torque;
    private final Float[] speed;

    public OpcuaCurve() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public OpcuaCurve(Float[] torque, Float[] speed) {
        this.torque = torque;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public Float[] getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public Float[] getTorque() {
        return torque;
    }

    @Override
    public ExpandedNodeId getTypeId() {
        return TYPE_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public ExpandedNodeId getBinaryEncodingId() {
        return BINARY_ENCODING_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public ExpandedNodeId getXmlEncodingId() {
        // XML encoding not supported
        return ExpandedNodeId.NULL_VALUE;
    }







    public static class Codec extends GenericDataTypeCodec<OpcuaCurve> {
        @Override
        public Class<OpcuaCurve> getType() {
            return OpcuaCurve.class;
        }

        @Override
        public OpcuaCurve decode(
            SerializationContext context,
            UaDecoder decoder) throws UaSerializationException {

            Float[] torqueArray = decoder.readFloatArray("motorTorque");
            Float[] speedArray = decoder.readFloatArray("motorSpeed");

            return new OpcuaCurve(torqueArray,speedArray);
        }

        @Override
        public void encode(
                SerializationContext context,
                UaEncoder encoder, OpcuaCurve value) throws UaSerializationException {

            encoder.writeFloatArray("motorTorque", value.torque);
            encoder.writeFloatArray("motorTorque", value.speed);
        }
    }

}
```

- and in register the decoder to the client like this:

```java
private void registerCustomCodec(OpcUaClient client) {
        NodeId binaryEncodingId = OpcuaCurve.BINARY_ENCODING_ID
                .local(client.getNamespaceTable())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("namespace not found"));

        // Register codec with the client DataTypeManager instance
        client.getDataTypeManager().registerCodec(
                binaryEncodingId,
                new OpcuaCurve.Codec().asBinaryCodec()
        );
    }
```